# Converting a matrix to a string and displaying it in a listbox.

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, listbox

I am using a pushbutton in a GUI in Matlab to open a dialog box that contains a listbox. I want the listbox to display an array. Here is the code I use in my GUI:

```
% --- Executes on button press in selectdata.
function selectdata_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to selectdata (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
w = getappdata(0,'wValue');
z = getappdata(0,'zValue');
A = [w,z];
str = mat2str(w);
[s,v] = listdlg('PromptString','Select a file:','SelectionMode','multiple','ListString',str);
```

The data A is something like:
         437        1203
         437        1207
         438        1168
         438        1146
         438        1101
         439        1203
         439        1174
         439        1146
         440        1118
         440        1148
         441        1236
         441        1166
         441        1142
         442        1171
         442        1180
         443        1258
         443        1200
         443        1097

I converted A to a string so that the listbox but would display it and it does, but my issue is that it displays the data horizontally. Is there a way of displaying it vertically?

Comment: The problem is `mat2str` uses Matlabs `;` instead of a new line, [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) should give the results you are after!

Comment: Perhaps you should post that as an answer. :)

Comment: Yes I think I will @RafaelMonteiro. :)

Comment: a = [123,456;456,789;789,012];
sprintf('%d ',a(:)) for the string. Does not know about the rest though.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro I shall do I didn't have time to write a nice answer but wanted to solve the problem for the asker...I will write up more nicely as an answer shortly when I have time

Comment: Sure, that was just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the output of `mat2str` which *"Convert(s) a 2-D matrix to a string in MATLAB syntax."* does not match the input format for [`listdlg's`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/listdlg.html)
parameter `'ListString'` which takes a values defined as a *"Cell array of strings that specify the list box items."*

So the `str` variable in the code should be a cell array of strings which can be generated as

```
str=cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(w),'UniformOutput',0)
```

### Keep reading... in this case its simpler than this...

---

**Luckily** the value pair for `ListString` can take char arrays as well, recognising the rows of the array as separate entries. Which means the output of [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) will work just fine...

```
str = num2str(w);
```

---

Back to the more complicated solution, why have I included that here?

Because the format of num2str only works nicely in this case as all they numbers have the same number of digits!

If the numbers in `w` had different numbers of digits then there would be leading spaces in the char array created by num2str, In which case the longer solution provides 'better' output.